# Given $\left(x + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right) = 1$, prove $\left(x + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right) = 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, contest-math, radicals

> Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers such that 
>   $$\left(x + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right) = 1$$ 
>   Prove that 
>   $$\left(x + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right) = 1$$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You'll find that the community tends to respond more favorably to questions that include some sense of what you know about a problem, and/or where you got stuck. Such information helps answerers target their responses to your skill level, without wasting anyone's time telling you things you already know. (Plus, it helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We'll replace $y$ an $-y$.

Thus, the given it's $$\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-y\right)=1$$ and we need to prove that:
$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}-y\right)=1.$$
Now, the condition gives
$$\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-y\right)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)$$ or
$$\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-y\right)-\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)+$$
$$+\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)-\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=0.$$ or
$$(x-y)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x\right)-\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)=0$$ or
$$(x-y)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}+x-\frac{(x+y)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+\sqrt{y^2+1}}\right)=0,$$ which gives $x=y$ because the second factor it's
$$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}-y\right)+(x+y)^2+1>0.$$
Id est, $$\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{y^2+1}-y\right)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\right)\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right)=1$$ and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint :**

By the hypothesis of the problem, do some algebra and show that :

$$\left(x + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \dots \Leftrightarrow y = -x$$

Now, substitute $y=-x$ on the expression $\left(x + \sqrt{1+x^2}\right)\left(y + \sqrt{1+y^2}\right)$ and see what happens.

Comment: How to prove $(x + \sqrt{1+x^2})(y + \sqrt{1+y^2}) = (x + \sqrt{1+y^2})(y + \sqrt{1+x^2})$?

Comment: @Success I updated my answer to a more straightforward one.

Answer (score 1):

Write $x=\tan a$ and $y = \tan b$ for some (angles) $a,b$. They exsist since $\tan $ is surjective function. Pluging in starting equation we get:

$$ {\sin a+1\over \cos a}\cdot {\sin b+1\over \cos b}=1$$
and after rearranging we get $$\sin(a)+ \sin(b) = \cos (a+b) - \cos 0$$

which is equivalent to $$2\sin{a+b\over 2}\cos{a-b\over 2} = -2\sin {a+b\over 2}\sin{a+b\over 2}$$

Case 1. $\sin {a+b\over 2}=0$ then $a+b = 2\pi k$ so $$x=\tan a = \tan (2\pi k-b) = -\tan b = -y$$

Case 2. $\sin {a+b\over 2}\ne 0$, then $$\cos {a-b\over 2}+\sin{a+b\over 2}=0$$ 
Factorising this we get:

$$2\cos ({\pi\over 4}-{b\over 2})\cdot \cos({a\over 2}-{\pi\over 4})=0$$

Now we have to choises again.

1.st: $${\pi\over 4}-{b\over 2} = {\pi\over 2}+\pi k\implies b =-{\pi\over 2}+2\pi k $$
so $y$ does not exist.

2.nd case... we get $x$ does not exsist.

So $x=-y$ and thus second expresins is also $1$.

Comment: Actually, $\sqrt{1+\tan^2a}\neq\frac{1}{\cos{a}}.$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg We can restrict $-\pi/2 < a < \pi/2$, so $x=\tan a$ is one-to-one

Comment: @Dylan Yes, of course!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Like [greedoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056689/given-leftx-sqrt1y2-right-lefty-sqrt1x2-right-1-prove/3056720#3056720), [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) let $x=\cot2A,y=\cot2B,0<2A,2B<\pi$ ([**Reference**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values) )

$$1=(x+\sqrt{1+x^2})(y+\sqrt{1+y^2})=\cot A\cot B$$

$\implies\tan A=\cot B$

$x=\cot2A=\dfrac{1-\tan^2A}{2\tan A}=\dfrac{1-\cot^2B}{2\cot B}=\cdots=-\cot2B=-y$